# How do I make a shared 2D array that multiprocessing.Pool will accept for computing pairwise statistics?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, multiprocessing

I would like to create a 2D array that can be accessed for read-only operations by multiple processes. My use case is to apply a function that takes pairs of columns from the 2D array (representing a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics))) and computes a [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(mathematics)) value (`float64`) depending on a `tuple` of additional arguments. A single call of function `f` would for a m-by-n array `X` with argument tuple `(a1, a2)` would look like `f(X, (a1, a2))`. In my use case I would like each process to compute `f` with different choices of `(a1, a2)`.

The most promising lead I have so far is [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39322905/4348400), but it uses a single-dimensional array. It also is using the array for non-reading purposes, but it was relevant at the time in terms of handling arrays.

I tried to modify that example by changing `a = mp.Array('i', [0]*10)` to `a = mp.Array('i', [[0]*10]*10)`, but I got the following traceback:

```py
>>> a = mp.Array('i', [[0]*10]*10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 141, in Array
    return Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, lock=lock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 88, in Array
    obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 67, in RawArray
    result.__init__(*size_or_initializer)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for `multiprocessing.Array`  (excerpt shown below), which has the argument `size_or_initializer`. The argument can only take an integer or a sequence, which I suppose `[[0]*10]*10` is neither given the aforementioned traceback.

> If size_or_initializer is an integer, then it determines the length of the array, and the array will be initially zeroed. Otherwise, size_or_initializer is a sequence which is used to initialize the array and whose length determines the length of the array.

So my main lead of using `multiprocessing.Array` is probably tanked. How can I build a 2D array that can be accessed (using Pool) for read-only operations?

Comment: Related (I still need to test this to see if it matches my use case): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320605/how-do-i-use-multiprocessing-pool-on-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting a `global` variable is effective at making it accessible to each process, which can be setup by passing an initialization function to `Pool`'s `initializer` parameter. I was concerned about passing a copy of the array to each process because it would require considerably more memory. Once this shared array is made accessible, the usual [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) operations can be performed as desired.

Here is a constructed example that selects pairs of variables from an array (being treated as a [data matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix)), and calculates the [correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between those pairs of [variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).

```py
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from multiprocessing import Pool

X = np.random.random(100000*10).reshape((100000, 10))

def function(cols):
    result = X[:, cols]
    x,y = result[:,0], result[:,1]
    result = pearsonr(x,y)
    return result

def init():
    global X 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(initializer=init, processes=4) as P:
        print(P.map(function, combinations(range(X.shape[1]), 2)))
```

This example illustrates how pairwise operations on random variables can be parallelized for scalability. Some advice for those that would like to calculate something other than correlation: replace `scipy.stats.pearsonr` with some other function that takes two arrays as arguments and this code will perform compute that function for all pairs. Naturally, replace `X = np.random.random(100000*10).reshape((100000, 10))` with code that appropriately loads your data into a 2D array representing a data matrix.